# What is the value of　$\frac 1 {0! + 1! + 2!} +\frac 1 {1! + 2! + 3!} + \frac 1 { 2! + 3! + 4!} + …?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the value of x?

$$e = 1 / 0! + 1 / 1! + 1 / 2! + … .$$

$$1 = 1 / (0! + 1!) + 1 / (1! + 2!) + 1 / (2! + 3!) + … .$$

$$(x = ) 1 / (0! + 1! + 2!) + 1 / (1! + 2! + 3!) + 1 / (2! + 3! + 4!) + … .$$

In my calculation by programming,
x is about 0.40037967700464134050027862710343065978234584790717558212650643072643052259740811195942853169077421.

If it is possible to find the value of x,
please tell me the value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $$k! + (k+1)! + (k+2)! = k!(k+2)^2,$$ so that the sum $$S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!+(k+1)!+(k+2)!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+2)^2 k!}.$$  This suggests considering the function $$f(z) = z e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{k+1}}{k!}.$$  Taking the integral gives $$g(z) = \int_{t=0}^z f(t) \, dt = (z-1)e^z + 1 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{k+2}}{(k+2)k!}.$$  Dividing by $z$ and integrating once again, we get $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{k+2}}{(k+2)^2 k!} = \int_{t=0}^z \frac{g(t)}{t} \, dt = e^z - 1 + \int_{t=0}^z \frac{e^t - 1}{t} \, dt,$$ for which the choice $z = 1$ yields $$S = e - 1 + \int_{t=0}^1 \frac{e^t-1}{t} \, dt.$$  This last integral doesn't have an elementary closed form; *Mathematica* evaluates it as $$\gamma - \operatorname{Ei}(1),$$ where $$\operatorname{Ei}(z) = -\int_{t=-z}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dt.$$